# Using Microsoft Log Parser, how would you do Hit count aggregates with IP counts?

Tags: iis, logging, analytics, logparser

I'm using MS Log Parser to do simple analytics against IIS logs.

I want a query that generates a report indicating the count of unique IPs hitting URLs, resulting in something like:

### URL | Unique_IPs | Total_Views

url1  3            100
url2  5            253

etc.

The problem I'm having is that Log Parser doesn't allow count(DISTINCT c-ip) when using a group by, and I need the group by to get the hit count per URL.

Anyone know how to do this kind of query in Log Parser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [Log Parser Rocks!](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/) - example *25) Unique visitors by day* should give you a starting point.

Because of the missing DISTINCT you'll have to create 2 queries.

---

*quoting from the above link to provide a full answer here*

25)  Unique visitors per day.  This requires two queries.  The first query selects from the IIS logs into a CSV file, and the second selects from that CSV file.

Query 1

```
logparser "SELECT DISTINCT cs-username, date 
INTO tempUniqueVisitorsPerDay.csv 
FROM logs\iis\ex*.log 
WHERE cs-username <> NULL 
GROUP BY Date, cs-username"
```

Query 2

```
logparser "SELECT date, count(cs-username) as UniqueVisitors 
INTO test.txt 
FROM tempUniqueVisitorsPerDay.csv 
GROUP BY date"
```